# Не импортируется telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Библиотека установлена
`pyTelegramBotAPI 3.7.6`
Но при импорте модуля telebot выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
> ```

Comment: а файл случаем называется не `telebot.py`?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению тут не всё так просто

Answer (score 0):

0. Посмотрите, может у вас установлена бибилиотека telebot, бибилиотека telebot и pytelegrambotapi не имеют никакого отношения.
1. Попробуйте установить pytelegrambotapi в виртульном окружении, подробнее здесь: https://python-scripts.com/virtualenv

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

pip uninstall telebot и
pip install pyTelegramBotApi

Это в терминал по очереди

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, чем именно ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего.

Comment: Подачей, а так смысл одинаковый